# req.body is not returning submitted data

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mongoose

I trying to learn MEAN stack and I am facing one issue. I have developed small Express app. But this one I couldn't figure out.

I am posting form data using Angular Http Service.

service code that uses post method to post data.

```
createUser(user: User): Observable<User> {
const submittedUser = JSON.stringify(user);
console.log("submitted:", submittedUser);
const headers = new Headers ({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/user/create', submittedUser, options)
  .map((response: Response) =>  {response.json()})
  .catch((error:Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
```

}

On server side I have app.js and one router file.

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var userRoutes = require('./routes/userRoutes');

var app = express();
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/go-social');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    next();
});

app.use('/user', userRoutes);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    return res.render('error');
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("App listening on port 3000");
})
```

This is router file. userRoutes.js

```
enter var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var User = require('../models/user');
router.post('/create', function (req, res) {

    console.log(req.body);
    var user = new User({
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    });
    user.save(function(err, result) {
        if(err) next(err);
        res.status(201).json({
            message: "Your account has been created successfully",
            obj: result
        });
    });
});
```

When I use Postman, it works, but it doesn't work with Http service. I am getting `req.body` in the console as object with my submitted object.

```
{ '{"firstName":"Myname","lastName":"sadf","email":"abc@gmail.com","password":"awe"}': '' }
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

**From**

```
const headers = new Headers ({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' })
```

**To**

```
const headers = new Headers ({  'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
```